# HTML / CSS - Cannot remove 'margin-top' from input boxes

Tags: html, css, forms

I can't seem to figure this out, maybe I am missing something, but this is my HTML:

```
<style type="text/css"> 
    #loginForm {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        outline: 0;
    }
</style>
```

```
<input id="loginForm" type='text' height="30px" width="20px" /><img id='usernameIcon' src="shipping3.png" width="30px" alt="username" height="30px"/>
```

Basically, I want the input box and the image right beside eachother. Both the input box and the image are the same height. I want them directly beside eachother, but for some reason, the input box has some sort of margin-top which makes it significantly below the image. Why is this?

I tested this on Chrome and IE 10 and on both, the input box has some sort of margin-top. I know that I can align them correctly with floats, but shouldn't there be another way to just remove that 'margin-top' from the input box?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set `vertical-align` to the same value for both element.

`height` and `width` attribut are not valid for `input` elements.

To keep borders within `height` given, you need to reset the box model via `box-sizing`.

**[DEMO](http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/HijbE)**

Basicly your CSS turns to be :

```
input, img {
  vertical-align:middle;/* or whatever else value */
  box-sizing:border-box
}
input {
  height:30px;
  width:20px;
}
```

---

To clarify about the `height` and `width` attribute for input type="text" :

Quote from : http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/input

---

> 4.10.5.1.2 Text (type=text) state and Search state (type=search)

When an input element's type attribute is in the Text state or the Search state, the rules in this section apply.

The input element represents a one line plain text edit control for the element's value.

The difference between the Text state and the Search state is primarily stylistic: on platforms where search fields are distinguished from regular text fields, the Search state might result in an appearance consistent with the platform's search fields rather than appearing like a regular text field.

If the element is mutable, its value should be editable by the user. User agents must not allow users to insert "LF" (U+000A) or "CR" (U+000D) characters into the element's value.

If the element is mutable, the user agent should allow the user to change the writing direction of the element, setting it either to a left-to-right writing direction or a right-to-left writing direction. If the user does so, the user agent must then run the following steps:

```
Set the element's dir attribute to "ltr" if the user selected a left-to-right writing direction, and "rtl" if the user selected a right-to-left writing direction.

Queue a task to fire a simple event that bubbles named input at the input element.
```

The value attribute, if specified, must have a value that contains no "LF" (U+000A) or "CR" (U+000D) characters.

The value sanitization algorithm is as follows: Strip line breaks from the value.

The following common input element content attributes, IDL attributes, and methods apply to the element: autocomplete, dirname, list, maxlength, minlength, pattern, placeholder, readonly, required, and size content attributes; list, selectionStart, selectionEnd, selectionDirection, and value IDL attributes; select(), setRangeText(), and setSelectionRange() methods.

The value IDL attribute is in mode value.

The input and change events apply.

The following content attributes must not be specified and do not apply to the element: accept, alt, checked, formaction, formenctype, formmethod, formnovalidate, formtarget, height, max, min, multiple, src, step, and width.

The following IDL attributes and methods do not apply to the element: checked, files, valueAsDate, and valueAsNumber IDL attributes; stepDown() and stepUp() methods.

---

End of quotes

Comment: do I need to give the img a box-sizing:border-box as well or is it not neccessary? For me, it worked with just giving input a box-sizing:border-box

Comment: by the way, over here: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_height.asp it gives the input element a width and height. Is it possible if you can send me the documentation where it says it is not valid?

Comment: it just doesn't work, and this is fine to me to tell it is not relevant/valid way to do . Beside, if there is a site i do not trust, it is W3schools wich has nothing to with w3C and has too many obsolete, out of date pages :)

Comment: @user2719875  http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/input  first col for text input ... width and height attributes are not accepted :)

Answer (score 4):

You should set the `vertical-align` of the input to top.

```
input { 
    vertical-align: top;   
    margin: 0;
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JrVMp/)

Answer (score 1):

did you add the relevant id to your input tag so that it can be targeted by your CSS selector?